# Cannot restore database to local (xampp)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have a wordpress webiste, and backed up all files including database, so from phpmyadmin im restoring the database file.

(sorry im new to sql and mysql)

And phpmyadmin giving me an error :

> ## SQL query:
>
> #### Table: `wp_options`
>
> #### Approximate rows expected in table: 193
>
> #### Delete any existing table `wp_options`
>
> #### DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `wp_options`
>
> ## MySQL said:
>
> #### 1046 - No database selected

[Picture of error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjcoZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add "use" command on the top to select db:

```
USE [database name];
```

Use the query below and set the result to a variable to check if table exists:

```
declare @ifExists int = 0;
set @ifExists = (SELECT COUNT(*)
                 FROM information_schema.tables 
                 WHERE table_schema = '[database name]' 
                 AND table_name = '[table name]';)
```

Then use @ifExists to decide whether you need to drop a table or not:

```
if @ifExists > 0
begin
   DROP TABLE [table name]
end
```

Comment: Sir im using the import method, should i use the query?
So i put this query and i run it by replacing what should be replaced right?
Cause in import method it isnt working
Thank you for your time

Comment: Because the backup of the database is with me on my laptop, compressed.

Comment: Can you try DROP TABLE [databasename].[dbo].[tablename] format?

Comment: I just realised that they are asking to put it like this format (using import method sir) ;  .[format].[compression] example, .sql.zip

but mine where i download it from wordpress plugin is xxxx.gz only; without .sql (even when extracting it)